# Switch primary group with LDAP user

Tags: permissions, suse

My version of usermod does not seem to support LDAP, so when I run

```
usermod -g <group> <username>
```

I get an error that the user name does not exist.
Is there a different way to switch my primary group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've got the proper tooling set up, you won't be able to change a user's primary GID from an LDAP client.  You will need to make the change on the LDAP server itself by modifying the `gid` attribute (or whatever attribute your schema uses to store primary GIDs) on the user object.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to change attribute *gidNumber* in the user's LDAP entry like user jayhendren said.

But I hope there is decent access control on the LDAP server so users **cannot** change their primary GID themselves.

Otherwise users could add themselves to any group gaining permissions on the Linux systems, effectively circumventing security controls.

My recommendation is to either...

- assign a single GID to all users and advice everybody to never assign any rights/permissions to it or...
- set user-only GIDs not used anywhere else

Comment: I believe that the question is really asking ‘‘How can the administrator switch the primary group of a user?’’  Can you answer that?

Comment: Basically I wanted to augment the other posters's answer with a word of caution.