# How change default usergroup?

Tags: linux, centos

I have CentOS 7, 
LDAP users: user1, user2
LocalGroup: MyGroup1
/etc/passwd

```
+user1::::::/bin/bash
```

/etc/group

```
MyGroup1:x:1256:user1,user2
```

Did try to change group:

```
usermod -g MyGroup1 user1
```

returned

```
usermod: user 'user1' does not exist in /etc/passwd
```

How solve this problem?

p.s. target - if I use user1 and create file/folder

-rw-r--r--    1 user1 **MyGroup1**         10 Apr  3 12:23 test13

NOT

-rw-r--r--    1 user1 **DefaultGroup**    10 Apr  3 12:23 test13

Comment: Related question: [Switch primary group with LDAP user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322660/switch-primary-group-with-ldap-user). Summary: edit the GID attribute for the user in the LDAP directory.

Comment: please write answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change name group in LDAP (login name change gid to gidNumber MyGroup1) or custome - you set schedule by ncron and `chown :MyGroup1 -R file/folder`